Triviality of deleted default constructor
Why do Clang and GCC consider s to be a trivial class type?
#include <type_traits>

struct s { s() = delete; };
static_assert(not std::is_trivial_v<s>); // clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok

For a class to be trivial, it needs to have at least one eligible default constructor that is trivial. By marking the default constructor of s as deleted, the implicit generation of the
default constructor is prevented. So, its default constructor is no longer eligible. Therefore, I would expect s not to be considered as a trivial type.
Demo

Just out of curiosity and laziness: what happens if you add a trivially constructible field to the struct?

looks like a bug to me.  Both here and here say the constructor must not be deleted and it must be trivially constructible which your class is not.

my guess: standard does not say as cppref (AFAIU) : "A trivially copyable class is a class:  that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move
assignment operator". By declaring a deleted default constructor, you declare it anyway, which may lead the compiler to implicitly declare the other special operators, which are trivial, thus fulfilling the requirement.

@Oersted The question is about a class being trivial or not. [class.prop]/2 requires a trivial class to have at least one eligible default constructor, where each eligible default constructor needs to be trivial.

my bad, I cited the wrong paragraph. Mine was for trivially copyable, not trivial (a few lines below...). What I don't understand in the wording is the meaning of "to have"... Does having a declared constructor enough? Even deleted? Which may explain clang and gcc behavior.

@Oersted The default constructor needs to be eligible and the standard clearly states, as per [special]/6, that an eligible default constructor cannot be deleted. Even if you read past this requirement, a trivial default constructor cannot be user-provided, as per [class.default.ctor]/3. So, it either needs to be implicitly generated or defaulted on its first declaration. Neither of which apply, since deleting a default constructor prevents the implicit generation of a default constructor.

You're right, thanks for the pointers. Thus I would be of the same opinion as NathanOlivier (btw he provided cppreference links that actually correspond to your standard ref. I totally missed them). Sorry for the useless "noise".

@303 Did my answer answer your question or is there anything you'd like me to clarify?

C++20 (N4868):

20.15.5.4 Type properties



Template
Condition




template<class T>struct is_trivial;
T is a trivial type (6.8)





6.8.1



[...] Scalar types, trivial class types (11.2), arrays of such types and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called trivial types. [...]





11.2



A trivial class is a class that is trivially copyable and has one or more eligible default constructors (11.4.5.2),
all of which are trivial.




Since s doesn't have one or more eligible default constrcutors it is not a trivial type and std::is_trivial_v<s> should therefore be false.
This means that both gcc and clang are wrong and gcc has an open bug report regarding this: #85723. The __is_trivial intrinsic function mentioned in the bug report is used directly by std::is_trivial_v.
